# Debug in Atmel Studio jumps to wild area of code when 'step out' is pressed

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, atmelstudio

Good day all!

I am running the latest Atmel Studio 7 with all patches.
AVR-GCC is being used with a 32U4 avr plus an Atmel-ICE via JTAG.

I am in an ISR function and step over works fine each time I press until I call a separate function.
When I get to this function I am on the 1st line of code.
The next press of step over does not go to the next line as it clearly should but jumps back to the middle of my ISR function in a random place.

The code is not working over all but did before the last few changes.

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had set the optimization to -o3 and then -os

when I set back to default -o1 ... all was well.

I guess the AVR-gcc can't handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by having the builds generate assembly listing files (`-Wa,adhlns`), and then also disassemblies of the final binary (`avr-objdump -h -S`). That gives me the possibility to examine the code which is actually generated, and to keep observing the changes to the generated code when I have changed the C source and rebuilt. (I have no idea how to actually do this this with Atmel studio, I only have experience with make and avr-gcc based buildsystems.)

Then I can check what compiler optimization options (`-O2` or `-O1` or `-O3` or `-Os` or ...) are in place, and how the selected optimization level distributes the assembly instructions of different C statements. AFAICT, on AVR, optimizing for size (`-Os`) automatically makes the code fast (every instruction takes the same time on AVR, so the less instructions, the smaller the code and the faster the execution), and the amount of instruction shuffling is very limited, so it is easy to read.

Comment: So is it true that for RISC or ARM one should always ... GCC -Os   ?

Comment: The AVR processor is very simple: It has one ALU, and it always fetches one instruction while the previous one is being executed. There are occasions when optimizing for size will even on a processor as simple as AVR result in longer execution times, e.g. when common code is put inside functions which are called and returned from with lots of register saves and restores as compared to just inlining the code. On more complex processors than the AVR, the connection between number of instructions and runtime will be more complex as well, so I can imagine all kinds of effects to happen there.

Comment: Well ... I am dead in the water really.   I will have to switch to another MCU and associated tools.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug an ISR don't forget that on break points cpu will stop, but all I/Os continue to run, and you probably a new interrupt will be triggered while you pressing next stop over, so other break points may be triggeredvand debugger stop on another place.

Are you enable interrupts before final RETI?